# jQuery select element and next together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an auto-generated HTML and I want to group together elements.

Input Html:

```
<div class="editor-label"><label for="StringField">StringField</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input id="StringField" type="text" value="" /></div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="IntField">IntField</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input id="IntField" name="IntField" type="number" value="0" /></div>

<!-- more like above -->
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="StringField">StringField</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input id="StringField" type="text" value="" /></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="IntField">IntField</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input id="IntField" name="IntField" type="number" value="0" /></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery's next selector to get those groups, and then wrap them, but I'm having trouble getting the items to select as one to use with `wrap()`. I'm not sure if I can write a single selector to get this, or if I will need to do it iteratively. Here are some of the selectors I've tried.

```
//selects just the labels
$('.editor-label')

//returns only the .editor-fields
$('.editor-label +  .editor-field')

//returns all 4 elements separately
$('.editor-label, .editor-label +  .editor-field')
```

What selector can I use to select the element (`.editor-label`) and it's next (`.editor-field`) as one "element"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to do the selection in a for each and not with a selector by itself.

```js
$(".editor-label").each(function() {
    var lab = $(this);
    var inp = $(lab).next();
    lab.add(inp).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
});
```

```css
.wrapper { border: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-label"><label for="StringField">StringField</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input id="StringField" type="text" value="" /></div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="IntField">IntField</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input id="IntField" name="IntField" type="number" value="0" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.editor-label').each(function(){
   var group = $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="form-group"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()`, `.addBack()` and `.wrapAll()`

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tobuxo/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
$('.editor-label').each(function(){
  $(this).next(".editor-field").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='form-group'/>");
});
```

`.each()` will target all the desired elements, inside the callback, find the `.next(".editor-field")`, addBack the starting selector (the current `.editor-label`) and `wrapAll()` inside the desired element

Comment: andSelf is deprecated

Comment: @AmitJoki I know I was just copying the code from my first jsbin. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **jQuery** `siblings` method:

```
$(".editor-label").siblings(".editor-label")
```

Comment: this will select all siblings

Answer (score 0):

See if  this will work.

```
var fields = $('.editor-field');
$.each(fields, function(index, obj){
    var field = $(obj);
    var label = field.prev('.editor-label');
    field.wrap('<div class='form-group'></div>').before(label);
});
```